# Byte Dropped Over Bluetooth Connection in Android

Tags: android, stream, bluetooth, buffer

I am having some issues with bytes being dropped over a bluetooth connection between an android device (Gingerbread 2.3.1) and a PC. The way I receiving the data is in a 2 byte buffer. The values being received is streaming from the PC over a few minutes (values represent a waveform). Here are just a few snippets of code so you can get the idea. The base of my code is from the [android bluetooth chat sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

```
BluetoothSocket socket;
```

...

```
mmInStream=socket.getInputStream;
```

...

```
byte[] buffer= new byte[2];
```

...

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

Has anyone has issues with this type of thing? The dropped bytes seem to happen at random times while at other times the values received are as expected. I am using a 2 byte buffer because the values I am receiving are 16 bit signed integers. From the PC side of things I am using RealTerm to send the binary files of data.

Is it possible that my buffer is too small and that is causing the dropped bytes?

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking the value of 'bytes'?

Comment: No I am not. Is it possible that buffer wouldn't be full when mmInStream.read(buffer) returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what the issue is. I want to thank [alanjmcf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35049/alanjmcf) for pointing me in the right direction.

I wasn't checking by `bytes` variable to see how many bytes were returned from the `mmInStream.read(buffer)`. I was simply expecting that every `buffer` returned would contain 2 bytes. The way i solved the issue was with the following code after getting the `buffer` back from the `InputStream`:

```
//In the case where buffer returns with only 1 byte
                if(lagging==true){
                    if(bytes==1){
                        lagging=false;
                        newBuf=new byte[] {laggingBuf, buffer[0]};
                        ringBuffer.store(newBuf);
                    }else if(bytes==2){
                        newBuf=new byte[] {laggingBuf, buffer[0]};
                        laggingBuf=buffer[1];
                        ringBuffer.store(newBuf);
                    }
                }else if(lagging==false){
                    if(bytes==2){
                        newBuf = buffer.clone();
                        ringBuffer.store(newBuf);
                    }else if(bytes==1){
                        lagging=true;
                        laggingBuf=buffer[0];
                    }
                }
```

This fixed my problem. Any suggestions on a better methodology?

Answer (score 2):

Following up to your answer.  You could just use a counter to remember how many bytes already read and compare it to the number wanted and also use it for the index to write the next byte(s).  See a C# version at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

```
public static void ReadWholeArray (Stream stream, byte[] data)
{
  int offset=0;
  int remaining = data.Length;
  while (remaining > 0)
  {
    int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
    if (read <= 0)
      throw new EndOfStreamException 
        (String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
    remaining -= read;
    offset += read;
  }
}
```